# how to pass arralylist in basic namevalue pairs in android

Tags: android

Hello Sir  i want send list of data to php server i use following code is it correct or not please tell me

```
        i try this code
           ArrayList<String>list1=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++)
    {
        JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);
        list1.add(e.getString("menuname"));
    }

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("menuname",list1.toString()));


        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.103/update.php");
        // "http://192.168.1.12/addnotes.php");
                //url+"Notes/addnotes.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Saved Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

please see the above code is correct or not .. please tell me

Comment: are u getting any error? of so then what? please post that too.

Comment: your code will works fine.. from server side you convert it the same and can parse the list..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you want to get content in String right than use this

```
String mResponseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

insetad of

```
  is= entity.getContent();
```

may it helps you